# NSubstitute: How to access actual parameters in Returns

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, nsubstitute

I would like to access actual parameter in NSubstitute `Returns` method. For example:

```
var myThing = Substitute.For<IMyThing>()
myThing.MyMethod(Arg.Any<int>).Returns(<actual parameter value> + 1)
```

Using NSubstitute what should I write in place of *`<actual parameter value>`*, or how can I achieve the equivalent behavior?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

According to [Call information documentation](http://nsubstitute.github.io/help/return-from-function/)

> The return value for a call to a property or method can be set to the
>   result of a function.

```
var myThing = Substitute.For<IMyThing>()
myThing
    .MyMethod(Arg.Any<int>())
    .Returns(args => ((int)args[0]) + 1); //<-- Note access to pass arguments
```

The parameter of the lambda function will give access to the arguments passed to this call at the specified zero-based position.

For strongly typed args the following can also be done.

```
var myThing = Substitute.For<IMyThing>()
myThing
    .MyMethod(Arg.Any<int>())
    .Returns(args => args.ArgAt<int>(0) + 1); //<-- Note access to pass arguments
```

> `T ArgAt<T>(int position)`: Gets the argument passed to this call at the specified zero-based position, converted to type `T`.

And since in this case there is only one parameter it can be simplified even further to

```
var myThing = Substitute.For<IMyThing>()
myThing
    .MyMethod(Arg.Any<int>())
    .Returns(args => args.Arg<int>() + 1); //<-- Note access to pass arguments
```

Here `args.Arg<int>()` will return the `int` argument passed to the call, rather than having to use `(int)args[0]`. If there were more than one then the index would be used.